# How to send encrypted data in post params

Tags: javascript, angular, api, encryption, mean-stack

```
From your app, 
POST https://api.quikr.com/app/auth/access_token 
Content-Type: application/json { “appId” : “app id”, “signature" : “”} 

signature = Hmac-sha1 ("app_secret", data) 
where data = email + appId + today’s date in yyyy-MM-dd format 
Response will contain the 'token' and the 'token_id'.
```

This is the document,

```
https://developer.quikr.com/index.php/documentation#developer_api
```

According to it ,Generating an access token

I tried as below but this code says error,

```
{error: true, message: "Invalid input Data"}
```

My code,

```
 this.data = 't@gmail.com12342018-01-31';
  var postData = {'appId':1242,'signature':Md5.hashStr("7777eh3y3ebe3y3e",this.data)};
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
this.http.post('https://api.quikr.com/app/auth/access_token', postData, { headers: headers })
```

Can anyone please suggest me help.Thanks.

Comment: You can test to stringify your appId. It could also be your signature.

Comment: First thing I would look at is, it's it says it's asking for a sha-1 hash and you're using Md5.

Comment: True, from the doc, `Md5.hashStr('blah blah blah', true) => raw:Int32Array(4)`.